# DateTime's offset gets lots when Service Bus message reaches Azure Function V1 (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, azure-functions, azureservicebus, datetimeoffset

It is important in our system to keep timestamps sent in messages by our IoT Devices. Messages go through IoT Hub and Service Bus to finally reach a Function.

An example of a message sent by IoT device is:

```
"body": {
  "type": "event_type",
  "timestamp": "2018-04-24T17:36:23+02:00"
}
```

It seems like Azure Function recognizes body type as JSON and automatically converts it to object - and date with offset string to Date. It is known issue in JavaScript that during such conversions timestamp gets lost (for example, see here: [JavaScript JSON Date Parsing and real Dates](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates)).

Is it possible to somehow omit this automatic conversion or introduce some kind of hook in the lifecycle which would alter this automatic conversion?

PS. I have started experimenting with overriding `JSON.stringify()` method. I will share in case it brings any results!

Comment: Are you using Functions V1 or V2? They handle JavaScript in different ways.

Comment: It's V1, added to the topic now!

Comment: Your data will not be altered if you use V2, although I'm not sure if that's what you want to do since it's still in preview (for now!). There is a "rawBody" property on HTTP objects that also is the unaltered version of the message, just as FYI.

Comment: I'll log this as a bug on V1! Since we're mainly focusing on developing V2 though, in full disclosure, it will likely be a bit before we get to fixing that bug

Comment: Thank you, @MarieHoeger. Any chance to get a tip on possible walkarounds in the meantime? Thanks!

Comment: @PawełSkorupiński - really sorry, no workarounds except to upgrade to V2 (Function app settings => Runtime version => beta). The heart of the issue is that our runtime (written in C#) deserializes the object with date parse handling (see fix for v2 https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/commit/d36d9eb0e4d98798af2974672a4e3a2a10de3c94). Fixing this in V1 would be a breaking change. An additive, non-breaking change to fix the issue isn't in scope for us :(